# Mysql> How to join data of 2 tables with single Query? (Select * and COUNT)

Tags: mysql

My sample data
Table 'posts':
| id (string)  | Author (int)| desc (string)|
| --- | --- |---|
| bac| 111| Hello|
| bak| 113| world|

table 'rating_info'
| post_id(string)| rating (int)|
| --- | --- |
| bak| 111 |
| bak| 112 |
| bak| 114 |
| bac | 114|
| bac | 114|

My end goal:

Somehow combine both tables, Select everything from Posts, but only select the COUNT from rating_info.

what i have tried:

```sql
SELECT (SELECT *
               AS posts
        FROM   posts
        WHERE  posts.id= 'bac')       AS posts,
       (SELECT Count(rating_info.post_id) AS count2
        FROM   rating_info
        WHERE  rating_info.post_id = 'bac') AS hits
```

error result:
#1241 - Operand should contain 1 column(s)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error comes from trying to display many columns AS posts.

You should use join:

```
SELECT *, Count(rating_info.post_id) AS count2 FROM posts
INNER JOIN rating_info ON rating_info.post_id = posts.id
WHERE posts.id = 'bac';
```

This displays all columns from both tables + the count, you can switch the * to specific columns instead.

Comment: That does work, but does not return the count from rating_info (sorry about the table, idk why its broken)

Comment: Try my update, didn't have my morning coffee yet ;) This displays all columns from both tables + the count, you can switch the * to specific columns instead.